# ¿Cómo cambiar color a una impresión de argumento en la consola? Java

Tags: java

Estoy buscando cambiar los colores con **system.out.println** en `java`:

```java
System.out.println("Quiero que este sea rojo");
System.out.println("Quiero que este sea cyan");
```

Ya intenté con el código de colores **ANSI**, pero en **Windows** sólo genera basura en la consola.

Comment: Puedes usar [ANSI_SCAPE_CODES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), ten en consideracion que funcionan en terminales Unix y no son soportados en Windows.

Comment: ¿No hay alguna opción para Windows (en IDE Eclipse)?, gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema como bien dices es que los códigos de colores ANSI no funcionan en Windows. Si lo único que te interesa es que eclipse muestre los colores en su consola, te bastaría con instalar la extension "ANSI Escape in Console"
[image: Extensión ANSI escapa para consola]

Un posible código para lo que planteas podría ser el siguiente:

```
public class Colores {
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "Quiero que esto sea rojo");
        System.out.println(ANSI_CYAN + "Quiero que esto sea cyan");
    }
}
```

[image: Resultado de la ejecución del programa]

Comment: Ummmm, muchas gracias. Quería saber si había una alternativa sin descargar librerías, pero al parecer no, gracias :D